# Prevent parent ng-submit with a child element directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following angular form I would like to prevent `ng-submit` if we are currently editing a field called `tags`, which is special, because using enter on tags submits the tag, not the form.

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="foo" />
  <input type="tags" ng-keyup="submitTag($event)" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And in angular

```
$scope.submit = function($event) {
  if ($event.keyCode == 13) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    return false;
    // What do I have to do?

  }
};
```

I've also tried binding the input to `ng-submit`. How do I prevent Angular from running the submit code if `keyCode == 13` **and** the user is editing tags?

Comment: Use keydown and you should be good. http://plnkr.co/edit/lUTJBL?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create a directive for this:

```
app.directive('tags',function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attr) {
            element.on('keydown',function(e) {
                if (e.which == "13") {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" tags>
```

Comment: Do I need to set a different priority level?

Comment: @BrianWheeler You dont need to.. `return false` will not work with angular handler, you need to use preventDefault() and use `keydown` `keyup` will be too late. http://plnkr.co/edit/lUTJBL?p=preview

Comment: Any dom handling should be done in a directive as thats what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by moving your submit button outside your form as shown below

```
<form name="myForm">
      <input type="foo" />
      <input type="tags" ng-keyup="submitTag($event)" />
    </form>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
  </body>

$scope.submit = function($event) {
    if (!$scope.myForm.$valid) {
             return;
        }

    alert('submit form');
  };

  $scope.submitTag = function(event){

    alert('submit tag');
  };
```

Here is a working plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/7G22wcR9UsbIsH9LtT11?p=preview

Comment: But I would like to be able to submit on enter, just not when focused on this specific field.

Comment: @BrianWheeler - Rob's solution works better than mine if you want to be able to submit the form on enter from other fields.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to creating a new directive is to just use angulars ngKeydown. *Note: Do not use ngKeyup b/c that event fires after ngSubmit.*

**Template:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="x" ng-keydown="$event.which === 13 ? fn($event) : null;" />
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.fn = function($event)
{
  if(_.isObject($event))
  {
    $event.preventDefault();
  }

  // Continue with whaterver this fn is supposed to do
};
```